# "unclassifiable statement" at if statement

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

Here is a MWE of a function in my code that is producing two errors when being compiled:

```
  function foo (a)

    implicit none
    real,  intent(in)::a
    real::foo

    if -1.0 < 0.0 then
       write(*,*) "hi"
    end if

    foo = a 

  end function foo
```

The errors I get at compile time are:

```
frag.f90:7063.8:
        if -1.0 < 0.0 then
        1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
frag.f90:7065.11:

        end if
           1
Error: Expecting END FUNCTION statement at (1)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting an unclassifiable statement at an `if` statement.  I believe the second error is tied to the first (if there's not `if` statement, no need to close it), so if the first error gets fixed the second one should get fixed as well.

I am compiling using `gfortran`.

Comment: When I teach, I always ask students to add brackets around conditions even if the programming language does not impose it. It is good for readability and debugging, and is indeed mandatory in fortran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the logical expression in brackets:

```
if (-1.0 < 0.0) then
```

The second error is indeed garbage and should be gone as soon as you fixed the statement.

---

From the Fortran 2008 Standard, Cl. 8.1.7.4 "IF statement":

> 1 The IF statement controls the execution of a single action statement based on a single logical expression.
>
> ```
> R837 if-stmt                  is IF ( scalar-logical-expr ) action-stmt
> ```

Comment: Python done spoiled me.